# Maps of discs into surfaces

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Let $f:D \to S $ be a continuous map from the closed unit disc in $R^2$ into a closed surface of genus $g \geq 1$ such that $f|_{\partial D}$ is an embedding (homeomorphism onto its image) with Image $\gamma$ a simple closed curve. Then, $\gamma$ bounds an embedded disc $D* \subset S$ and I wonder if it is true that $D* \subset f(D)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the answer for not necessarily compact manifolds of arbitrary dimension. It uses significantly more machinery than the other answer.

Let $M$ be a simply connected manifold with sphere boundary $S$, and let $M'$ be the manifold obtained by filling in the boundary with a disc. If the inclusion $S \hookrightarrow M$ is null-homotopic, then $M = D^n$. A null-homotopy gives me a map $(D^n,S) \to (M,S)$, and I can complete this to a map $S^n \to M'$ of degree 1. By Poincare duality this is an isomorphism on cohomology (if $M'$ has a nontrivial cohomology class $\alpha \in H^k(M')$, there is some $\beta \in H^{n-k}(M')$ with $\alpha \smile \beta \neq 0$; invoke that we have a nontrivial homomorphism $H^*(M') \to H^*(S^n)$. Do this with $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z/p$ coefficients to kill all torsion and non-torsion cohomology.) The assumption that $M$ is simply connected implies by Whitehead that it's a homotopy equivalence. Hence by the generalized topological Poincare conjecture $M'$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$ and $M$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$ as desired.

(This is even easier if $M$ is not simply connected; just lift the map from the disc to the universal cover of $M$ and fill in the other boundary components to get a non-surjective map of degree 1.)

Now suppose I had an embedded sphere $S \subset M$ (with a tubular neighborhood) that bounded a ball on one side. Call the other side (with $S$) $M'$. Suppose I had an extension to the disc $D \to M$ of this map that did *not* surject onto the ball. Then by puncturing I would see that this implies that the inclusion of the boundary $S \subset M'$ is null-homotopic. The above then implies that $M' = D^n$ as desired.

I never actually needed that $M$ was compact here!

Comment: It is not clear to me why you can get a degree 1 map from $S^n$ to $M'$ in your setup. You implicitly use this later, since this implies that $M'$ is a closed, orientable manifold, allowing you to use Poincaré duality in the first place. Also, I don't understand your argument of why $H^k(M') = 0$ for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$. (It is clear to me in the cases $k=1,n-1$, because M, and therefore M', is simply-connected).

Comment: @BerniWaterman: The argument must be modified again for noncompact manifolds, but this can be done. Simply connected manifolds are orientable, and I can use the local degree formula on the map to count the degree by looking at the part I extended over the ball (which is a homeomorphism). What in particular is troubling about the argument that $H^i(M)$ is zero?

Comment: I am only familiar with the degree formula for maps from $S^n$ to itself. However, I just realized that the map $f: S^n \to M'$ you described must indeed induce an isomorphism in top homology. This can be seen by looking at the composition of this map with the quotient map, identfying $M$, along with its boundary, to a point. One then gets a map from S^n to itself that is a homotopy equivalence, and thus, must be an iso on top homology. This implies that $H_n(M) = \mathbb Z$ and the fact that $f_*$ is an iso.

Comment: The degree formula works for arbitrary closed oriented n-manifolds, with the same proof.

Comment: Yes, but note that my argument even works *without* assuming a priori that $M$ is compact (and $M'$ therefore closed). Furthermore, if $M'$ has dimension at least $4$, I don't see why Poincaré duality implies that $H^i(M')= 0$. Why, for example, should it be true that $H^2(M') = 0$?  And what is the non-trivial homomorphism from $H*(M')$ to $H*(M)$?

Comment: The map $H^*(M') \to H^*(M)$ is an isomorphism in all degrees but $n$ by Mayer-Vietoris. But we don't need this; we just need to show that $M'$ is $S^n$ to deduce that $M$ is $D^n$. I still don't know what your objection to my argument that $H^i(M') = 0$ is.

Comment: @BerniWaterman: Oh! I'm sorry, I typo'd. We have a nontrivial homomorphism $H^*(M') \to H^*(S^n)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30663/discussion-between-berni-waterman-and-mike-miller).

Comment: I think your argument that $f_*$ induces an isomorphism on homology deserves further explanation. You explained perfectly well why $M'$ can only have torsion elemets in the lower (reduced) homology groups, by using the naturality of cup product and the fact that $f^*$ is *injective* on top-cohomology. For this argument, it doesn't matter wheter or not $f^*$ is really also surjective. But somehow, you have to use this fact when you pass to field coefficients, in order to show that there are also no torsion elemets. It isn't true in general:

Comment: The projection map $\pi: S^3 \to RP^3$ has degree $2$ but clearly, $RP^3$ has non-trivial torsion homology

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking me why $f^*$ is surjective? That's exactly what it means to assume the map $S^n \to M$ is degree 1.

Comment: No, I am making it apparent that in your argument of why $M'$ has trivial lower (co-)homology, you didn't actually use the fact that $f^*$ is surjective, at least in my humble eyes. The example i gave is making it obvious why you should.

Comment: Ok. I am satisfied with this answer and will no longer comment on it. If you would like to clarify further, feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Cute question. Supposing the genus is at least zero, yes. (If you were working on the sphere you could take your map-from-disc to be the top hemisphere and the chosen embedded disc to be the bottom hemisphere.)

For suppose not. Then there's some point $x$ in the interior of $D^*$ that the image of the disc misses. Then the boundary curve $\gamma$ is a loop around $x$ that's null-homotopic in the surface with that point deleted. But the punctured genus $g$ surface deformation retracts onto the wedge of $2g$ circles (draw a picture of the fundamental domain with the puncture in the middle!) and this loop $\gamma$ maps to the (nontrivial) word $[a_1,b_1]\cdots [a_g,b_g]$ in $\pi_1(\vee_{2g} S^1) = F_{2g}$, the free group on $2g$ generators.

So $\gamma$ is *not* null-homotopic in $\Sigma_g \setminus \{x\}$, and this is a contradiction. So $D^* \subset f(D)$.

Comment: Such an elegant, easy answer, that I feel almost bad not having come up with it. Thank you! As a follow up, I wonder if its also true that f (D) is also always an embedded disc ( I dont imply that f is an embedding, which can of course be false).

Comment: @Berni: I can break that for silly reasons. For instance, have the disc "reach around" so that its image is an annulus. You could even have the image of the disc be the whole surface. It's usually impossible to get point-set constraints on the images of maps; the best you can usually do is up to homotopy. (For instance, $f$ here is homotopic to an embedding. This is reminiscent of the 3-manifold loop and sphere theorems.)

Comment: True. And by the way, you can kind of extent my original question to the case g=0 in such a way that ONE of the two discs bounded by $\gamma$ will be contained in the image. This is done by assuming the contrary, taking out one point in each disc that is not in the image and applying essentially your argument

Comment: Right, that works like a charm.

Comment: I guess its also true for general (non-closed) surfaces, how would one try to prove it there ? Another remarkable thing is that this is exclusive to 2 dimensional manifolds. One can quite easily bend and deform an embedded disc in 3-space, while leaving the boundary untouched, such that it wont admit any embedded disc as a subset with the same boundary. Generally, to show that there even exists an embedded disc in 3-space with the same boundary is a different beast on its own  (loop theorem). Can at least this result be extended to 4 dimensions and higher ?