# Degree of maps and coverings

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

Following a recent question I had concerning degree $1$ maps from spheres, I came up with an assumption, which might either be very easily proven false, or, if not, still hasn't been answered. It goes as follows:

*Let $M$ be a closed, orientable $n$-manifold and $f: S^n \to M$ a map of degree $m$. Then $S^n$ is a $k$-sheeted covering space of $M$*, where $k$ is some divisior of $m$.

Some remarks:

- Since degree $1$ maps from the sphere are *precisely* homotopy equivalences (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505481/degree-1-maps-from-mathbb-sn)), the *generalized Poincaré-conjecture* in the *TOP*-category follows as a special case for $m=1$.
- This assumtion can very easily be proven false if $S^n$ is replaced by a general $n$-manifold. For $n=2$, there is a simple map of degree $1$ from $S_g$, the surface of genus $g \geq 1$, to $S^2$ as a result from collapsing the 1-skeleton (in its elementary CW-structure) to a point.
- It is also false to assume that $f$ has the homotopy-type of an $m$-sheeted cover. I believe I have read that already for $m=1$, there are some highly non-trivial counterexamples in dimension 6 or higher.

Can somebody enlighten me on this ?!

*Edit:* In my original question, I assumed that the degree of the cover would have to equal the degree of the Initial map. This is easily proven false by considering maps from $S^n$ to itself that are suspensions of the map $z \to z^m$ on $S^1$. This has degree $m$.

*Edit 2:* As suggested by Eric Wofsey, an equivalent assumption would be the following:

*Let $M$ be a closed, simply-connected $n$-manifold with $M \neq S^n$ and let $f: S^n \to M$ be a map. Then $deg(f)=0$*.

Now it becomes obvious that one has to go to dimension at least $4$, in order to find counterexamples.

Comment: By lifting $f$ to the universal cover of $M$, this is equivalent to saying that there are no maps of positive degree from $S^n$ to any simply connected closed manifold which is not a sphere.

Comment: Indeed, and it seems like a much more concise statement in itself. You don't even have to restrict this assumption to non-existence of positive degree maps from $S^n$ to such a space. Any negative degree candidate could be precomposed with a reflection to produce a map of positive degree. Hence, the best way to ask this question would be: For $M \neq S^n$ a closed and simply-connected manifold and $f: S^n \to M$ a map, does it follow that $deg(f) = 0$ ?

Comment: By a Poincare duality argument very similar to the answer to your previous question, you can show that $H^*(M,\mathbb{Z})$ for $0<*<n$ must consist entirely of torsion whose order divides a power of $\deg(f)$ (i.e., $H^*(M,\mathbb{Z}[\deg(f)^{-1}])=0$).

Comment: Yes, I have come to the same result. Does it help ?

Comment: Such manifolds should exist in dimension 5, which is the first place you can have simply connected rational homology spheres (or at least can't obviously not). If you can come up with an example of a degree 2 map $S^5 \to M$ I'd love to see it - I need something like that to finish off my answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1494524/98602) and construct a counterexample in dimension 5.

Comment: Also, if this was true, we will have to use the Poincaré conjecture at some point of the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, such a thing needs to be a rational homology sphere, and in particular a $\Bbb Z[1/d]$-homology sphere, where $d$ is the degree. It also needs to have fundamental group of order coprime to $d$. As in the comments, we may as well assume the manifold is simply connected by passing to the universal cover.

First, there are no simply connected rational homology spheres in dimensions 3 or 4 other than $S^4$, up to homeomorphism - Poincare duality forces the integral homology to be $H^*(S^n)$, and you can pick a degree 1 map $M \to S^n$, which is hence a homotopy equivalence; now invoke the Poincare conjecture.

The first place this is possible is dimension 5, and there are examples in all dimensions at least 5, as produced by Danny Ruberman in [this paper](http://library.msri.org/books/Book32/files/ruberman.pdf). Indeed, he points out that *as long as $M$ is a simply connected $\Bbb Z[1/d]$-homology sphere*, there is a map $S^n \to M$ of degree $d^r$ for some $r$. A very explicit example of such a manifold is $SU(3)/SO(3)$, a simply connected 5-manifold whose homology is $H_2 = \Bbb Z/2$, $H_0 = H_5 = \Bbb Z$, and all others zero (which I got from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/214730/40804)).

Here is a precise statement of the "Hurewicz mod $\mathcal C$" theorem he invokes:

Let $\mathcal C$ be the set of finite abelian groups, or abelian $d$-groups (meaning groups whose orders have the same prime divisors as $d$). (There are other choices of $\mathcal C$ that work, but I don't remember the precise requirements.) Then if $\pi_k(X) \in \mathcal C$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n-1$, then $H_k(X) \in \mathcal C$ as well for $i \leq k \leq n-1$, and the Hurewicz map $h: \pi_n(X) \to H_n(X)$ is an isomorphism mod $\mathcal C$, which means that the kernel and cokernel of $h$ are both in $\mathcal C$.

In our specific case, by assuming that $M$ was a $\Bbb Z[1/d]$ homology sphere means we can induct upwards to see that $\pi_k(X)$ must also be in $\mathcal C$,  and finally conclude that the map $\pi_n(X) \to H_n(X) = \Bbb Z$ has finite abelian cokernel - and in particular, the map has nontrivial image. We get the precise statement about a map of degree $d^r$ by picking $\mathcal C$ the be the set of $d$-groups.

Comment: A possible way of how to construct such a map of degree $2$ is to consider first for arbitrary $n \geq 2$ and $n$ odd the canonical projection $p : S^n \to RP^n$. On the generator of $\pi_1(RP^n)$, we can perform surgery to effectively "kill" the fundamental group, call the resulting space $X$. Such a surgery will only affect the 1'st and the n-1 homology of $RP^n$, so if $n \geq 5$, $X$ will be a rational homology sphere not homeomorphic to $S^n$. There is a way to extend the projection $p$ to $X$ and this map will have the same degree as $p$, so will be of degree $2$.

Comment: @Berni: Nice construction.